# I need to write Update statement in sybase

Tags: sql, sql-update, sybase, sap-ase

Here is my table if we observe it there are 6 match_ids and in those 3 are 795 and 3 are td party and some unique match_ids.

What I need is if there are duplicate match_ids with same party I need first row of duplicate to be marked as x and if there are no duplicate for them I need them also marked as x.

If I use this query:

```
select distinct match_id,party , count(match_id) from temp_table 
group by match_id,party having count(*) > 0
```

I am able to get count but how to select from there?

---

Present table:

```
match_id ------------ party--------  ind    
413082597------------ co-795    ---------                      
413082597------------ co-795                        
413082597------------ TD     
413082597------------ TD
413082597------------ TD
424421945-------      co-3376
424421946-------      co-3376
```

What needed is:

```
match_id -----    party ---------   ind
413082597------- CO-795   -----------x
413082597--------CO-795
413082597--------CO-795
413082597------ TD   ---------------x
413082597----   ----TD
413082597---------TD
424421945-------CO-3376------------   x
424421946----   CO-3376  ----------------x
```

Comment: You need some sort of unique id.

Comment: Please provide an example code and what is the expected result.

Comment: how do you determine which duplicate to flag as 'x'? are there other columns in the table you plan on using to help determine which rows to flag as 'x'?

Comment: there are. but I should select by match_id and party.  when we get set of duplicates the first row should be marked as x in IND column from those duplicate set. this when when other unix script run this and get a distinct values

Comment: Please define what "first" means for your rows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon Linoff.  You need an additional field to define a sort order so that one row can be designated "first".  Assuming that you sort ascending on the seq column, the SQL would be something like

```
SELECT match_id, party, 
     IF EXISTS SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.match_id = t1.match_id
         AND t2.party = t1.party
         AND t2.id < t1.id
     THEN "" ELSE "x"
     END

FROM table t1
ORDER BY match_id, party, seq
```

The above code will generate a "x" for singleton rows.  If I read your request correctly, this is what you want.

Another possibility is to add the flag (x or blank) column to the temp table, and process in sort order with a cursor to add an x to each row unless the previous row had the same key values.  Then select in sort order including the flag row DESC.